# Slideshow forward code overriding back button code

Tags: lua, slideshow, coronasdk, back-button

This code in scene1...

```
local composer = require ( "composer")
  local scene = composer.newScene()

    local function showScene2()
            local options = {
                effect = "slideLeft",
                    time = 130,
                    }
  composer.gotoScene("scene2", options)
  end
```

...is overriding this code, also in scene1...

```
local object = display.newImage("images/goBackBtn.png", 240, 250)
  object.name = "button object"

  local function onObjectTap( self, event )
  composer.gotoScene( "firstBar1" )
        return true
            end
  object.tap = onObjectTap
  object:addEventListener( "tap", object )
  sceneGroup:insert( object )
```

The back button works. It shows the firstBar1 scene, but only for an instant.

Then the next scene, scene2, comes on screen and the slideshow continues. (The order is firstBar1, scene1, scene2, scene3 and so on). All the scenes have a back button to firstBar1.

Why won't the slideshow go back to firstBar1 and stop there? How can I correct it?

This is related to a previous query which one commentator suggested I clarify:  "Back button does not navigate to required scene".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you have a timer performed on the firstBar scene ..If so, every time you show the firstBar1 scene, you call the showScene2 function() .. so every time you go back to the scene the timer is performed ..
I suggest you pass a param when tapping the back button to stop the timer, or even to decide to use the timer or not.

so I would add to the back button

```
 local function onObjectTap( self, event )
  composer.gotoScene( "firstBar1",{params = {timer = "stop"} )
   return true
  end
```

on the firstBar scene

```
local params = event.params

if (params.timer ~="stop") then
timer.performWithDelay(2000, showScene2 )
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but can't make it work. firstBar1 doesn't have a timer, just a forward button to send it to scene1. Can this code be modified? if (params.timer ~="stop") then
timer.performWithDelay(2000, showScene2 ) I've tried but with no success. Thanks.